# Orthogonal matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Could really use some insight/help here - really appreciate it!

Suppose that $G$ is a matrix of order $n$ such that $G^{T}G = I$. Let $x_{1}, \dots,x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be pairwise orthogonal vectors $(x_i \cdot x_j = 0$ for everypair $x_i, x_j$ with $i \neq j).$ Show that $Gx_1,\dots, Gx_k$ are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: Use the formulation $\langle x, y \rangle = x^T y$ when $x$ and $y$ are written as $n \times 1$ column vectors - then apply that to calculate $\langle G x_i, G x_j \rangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
Gx_i. Gx_j &= (Gx_i)^T(Gx_j) \\ &=x_i^T G^TG x_j \\&= x_i^T x_j \\&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show me some of the intermediate steps? Cheers!

Comment: Edited the post.